# Fastest approach to colorize pixel by other pixel

Tags: colors, formula, photoshop, blending, color-blending

Subject. I want to achieve colorization of one pixel by other pixel like "Color" blending mode in Photoshop (with 100% opacity).
What I do now:

1. get hue of mask pixel;
2. convert source pixel from RGB to HSL;
3. replace hue and convert back to RGB;

If you are interested in the formula - check this: [Please explain this color blending mode formula so I can replicate it in PHP/ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121393/please-explain-this-color-blending-mode-formula-so-i-can-replicate-it-in-php-ima)

But for this task converting back'n'forth from/to HSL/RGB seems too excessive.

So I am looking for a faster approach. I guess there should be way to calculate RGB-multiplying coefficients somehow and then for source pixel just simply do something like this:

```
 src_R *= mult_R;
 src_G *= mult_G;
 src_B *= mult_B;
```

---

UPD: Actually I don't need it to be **exactly** like in Photoshop. I mentioned PS blending mode just for example. I use it in my custom convolving routine, so I want it to be fast, but precision is not important, so it even if it could be approximated by a few percents. It's just that I want to find an approach to change pixel's tone without these complex HSL/RGB conversions...

---

UPD2: After some tests I've realized that my approach (replacing hue) is actually pretty far from what I wanted. Also after some digging I've found that "Color" blend-mode in PS replaces not only Hue but also Saturation. And surprisingly that makes algorithm not more complex, but on a contrary a bit simpler (faster):

1. we need to get not only Hue, but also Saturation of mask-pixel
2. but now we don't need to convert src-pixel from RGB to HSL, cuz all
   we need is luminocity which calculated much faster than full
   RGB->HSL routine...
3. with src-Luminocity, mask-Hue and Sat. we convert it to RGB...

It is still pretty complex though, and I still believe it could be simplified.

Comment: If accuracy is not that important, maybe you could make a lookup table (LUT) with just 64 pre-calculated entries and round your values to the nearest 4 before looking up.

Comment: @MarkSetchell it's nice idea, didn't thought bout cache-tables. But i don't get it bout 64 entries...  I don't rly sure what i should put in the table lol)) if i knew how to get multiplying coefficients - the table will not be needed, but with this hue approach i don't see how can i use the table at all

Comment: It would help, if you were to post example input and output images showing what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can do Photoshop-like blending in ImageMagick using -compose colorize or -compose luminize. What is done is to transfer either the intensity (luminance) channel between images (luminize) or the combination of Hue and Saturation channels (colorize) between images, via RGB->HCL->RGB colorspace.

Note that it is usually easier to add color than to remove it. But I try to do the latter here.

Input Images:

[image]

[image]

You can make the first image look more like the second image using either -compose luminize or -compose colorize. It just depends upon the order of the two input images.

```
convert zelda1.jpg zelda1_tint.jpg  -compose colorize  -composite result.jpg

convert zelda1_tint.jpg zelda1.jpg -compose luminize -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

If you reverse the order, then you get:

```
convert zelda1_tint.jpg zelda1.jpg -compose colorize -composite result2.jpg

convert zelda1.jpg zelda1_tint.jpg -compose luminize -composite result1.jpg
```

[image]

I am not sure which way you want to go.

If you take the latter and add some brightness and contrast, then you can get closer to the first image.

```
convert zelda1.jpg zelda1_tint.jpg -compose luminize -composite -brightness-contrast 15,-5 result1.jpg
```

[image]

Another approach is to match the brightness (mean) and contrast (standard deviation) between the two images. I use one of my Unix bash shell scripts to do that.

The matching uses the mean and standard deviations from each 
image according to the equation: `(I2-Mean2)/Std2 = (I1-Mean1)/Std1`.
This equation represents a normalized intensity such that it has zero mean 
and approximately the same range of values due to the division by the 
standard deviations. We solve this equation to form a linear transformation 
between I1 and I2 according to `I2=A*I1+B`, where `A=(Std2/Std1)` is the slope 
or gain and `B=(Mean2-A*Mean1)` is the intercept of bias. The matching can be done in different colorspaces. Here I use LAB, but it can also be done in RGB or YCbCr.

See also https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/ and http://im.snibgo.com/gainbias.htm

```
matchimage -c lab zelda1_tint.jpg zelda1.jpg result.jpg
```

[image]

Finally another way is to use histogram matching between two images. I use one of my scripts to do that. It also can do that in various colorspace. Here I use RGB. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching

```
histmatch -c rgb zelda1.jpg zelda1_tint.jpg result3.jpg
```

[image]

As you can see, this seems to be the better approach in this case.

For anyone interested, my scripts can be found at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.html